# What's the best way to easily launch programs across multiple linux servers that can't be headless?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vnc, headless

I'm trying to launch a program across many Ubuntu servers that can not be headless. I would need to relaunch these every few days so I'm looking for a way to easily do this. I installed a VNC Server on one linux machine and I'm able to launch my program by connecting to that but the problem is it takes effort to manually open up TightVNC and then open the terminal inside the TightVNC GUI to run the command to launch the program.

What I want ideally is to write one line in the terminal on my local windows machine to launch this program on my server and then even if my local computer was to turn off, I would still have this program running on the server.

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot be headless"? It's important to understand why those programs need parents since the answer depends on it. Also, how do you start the programs today on multiple servers? You connect to one server using `TightVNC`, but then how do you connect to the rest, using `ssh`? And why don't you login to your VNC server with `ssh` from Windows instead of the GUI?

Comment: @aviro It's a .jar file and if I run it without VNC it produces an error 'java.awt.headlessexception'. At the moment I've just been testing it on one server by connecting to it with TightVNC and then launching it through the terminal with that. My problem is that 1. If my local computer running TightVNC shuts down, then I believe the .jar application will close as well since it will be running headless and 2. I need to manually open up the TightVNC Gui for each server which will be tedius. Could this be fixed by logging into the VNC server with ssh like you suggested?

Comment: _"If my local computer running TightVNC shuts down, then I believe the .jar application will close as well since it will be running headless"_ - Are you sure of that? You local computer runs the `VNC` **viewer**. The remote machine runs the `VNC` **server**, which means that the display keeps running even if you're not connected to it. Second thing, does your `java` program require GUI interface? If not, you can try adding to the command line: [`-Djava.awt.headless=false`](https://rollbar.com/blog/java-headlessexception/). Let's start by answering those questions and continue then.

Comment: @aviro the java program requires a GUI interface. When I use the headless = false I get Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable. Does what you say mean I just need to connect to the VNC server once with my VNC viewer initially and the display will keep running until I shut down the VNC server on the machine?

Answer (score 0):

Is the program you need to run a GUI app, or a text-only program?

You mention opening a terminal, so I assume it's a text program.  If that's the case, you don't need to use VNC, you can use `ssh`.

If you need the program to keep running even if the ssh connection dies, you can use `nohup` or run it inside a terminal multiplexer like `tmux` or `screen`.  You may have to reconfigure systemd if it's configured to kill all user processes on logout:

1. Edit `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`
2. Add a line with `KillUserProcesses=no` (there may already be a commented-out line already in logind.conf - you can just uncomment it)
3. Save and exit
4. Run `systemctl daemon-reload`

All of the above have to be done as root, of course.

Comment: It's a .jar file that opens a GUI app and if I run it without VNC it produces an error 'java.awt.headlessexception'.

Answer (score 0):

from EPEL, check out `pdsh` or *parallel distributed shell*.

```
================================================================================
 Package                Arch            Version             Repository     Size
================================================================================
Installing:
   pdsh                   x86_64          2.34-5.el7          epel          114 k
Installing for dependencies:
   pdsh-rcmd-ssh          x86_64          2.34-5.el7          epel           15 k


   man pdsh

   pdsh is a variant of the rsh(1) command. Unlike rsh(1), which runs com‐
   mands on a single remote host, pdsh can run multiple remote commands in
   parallel.  pdsh  uses a "sliding window" (or fanout) of threads to con‐
   serve resources on the initiating host while allowing some  connections
   to time out.
```

If you set up SSH keys between your servers to allow passwordless login, as is done in clusters between the head node and its compute nodes, pdsh works very well.